# Outputting a square wave at a specific frequency in verilog

Tags: audio, verilog

so I'm trying to produce sound via an audio controller by creating a square wave at various frequencies depending on which switch gets flipped on an FPGA. I'm using an audio controller that has a chip clock of 48kHz, so I'm using a clock divider (one for each note, it's not necessary now but it will be later if you're wondering why I'm doing that) to count the duty cycle for each note, flipping between +amplitude and -amplitude every half duty cycle. For some reason I am able to get audio to output, but the tone of the notes do not represent the frequency I gave them (the tones are seemingly random, and much higher pitched than they should be). I've searched the internet dry and cannot come up with a solution as to why this is... any help is much appreciated!

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
// Positive and negative amplitude parameters for square wave
parameter pos_amp = 32'h7FFFFFFF;
parameter neg_amp = 32'h80000000;

// Determines channel_audio_out via dac_out
wire signed [32:1] channel_audio_out = dac_out ? pos_amp : neg_amp;

// Seperate 8-bit counter for each note
reg [7:0] ac_counter_C4;
reg [7:0] ac_counter_D4;
reg [7:0] ac_counter_E4;
reg [7:0] ac_counter_F4;
reg [7:0] ac_counter_G4;
reg [7:0] ac_counter_A4;
reg [7:0] ac_counter_B4;

reg clear_audio_out_memory;             // To clear audio_out buffer when no SW is flipped
reg write_audio_out;                            // To signal when to write to audio_out buffer
reg dac_out;                                    // Determines pos_amp or neg_amp for channel_audio_out

// Determines dac_out via ac_counter's (AUD_XCK dividers)
always@(posedge AUD_XCK) // 48kHz
begin
    clear_audio_out_memory <= 1'b0;
        if (SW[0] == 1'b1) // C4 --- f = 261.626 Hz --- Duty Cycle = 184
            begin
                ac_counter_C4 <= ac_counter_C4 + 1'b1;
                if (ac_counter_C4 >= 8'd183)
                    ac_counter_C4 <= 8'd0;
                write_audio_out <= 1'b1;
                dac_out = (ac_counter_C4 < 8'd92) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
            end
        else if (SW[1] == 1'b1) // D4 --- f = 293.665 Hz --- Duty Cycle = 164
            begin
                ac_counter_D4 <= ac_counter_D4 + 1'b1;
                if (ac_counter_D4 >= 8'd163)
                    ac_counter_D4 <= 8'd0;
                write_audio_out <= 1'b1;
                dac_out = (ac_counter_D4 < 8'd82) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
            end
        else if (SW[2] == 1'b1) // E4 --- f = 329.628 Hz --- Duty Cycle = 146
            begin
                ac_counter_E4 <= ac_counter_E4 + 1'b1;
                if (ac_counter_E4 >= 8'd145)
                    ac_counter_E4 <= 8'd0;
                write_audio_out <= 1'b1;
                dac_out = (ac_counter_E4 < 8'd73) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
            end
        else if (SW[3] == 1'b1) // F4 --- f = 349.228 Hz --- Duty Cycle = 138 // Wrong note completely
            begin
                ac_counter_F4 <= ac_counter_F4 + 1'b1;
                if (ac_counter_F4 >= 8'd137)
                    ac_counter_F4 <= 8'd0;
                write_audio_out <= 1'b1;
                dac_out = (ac_counter_F4 < 8'd69) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
            end
        else if (SW[4] == 1'b1) // G4 --- f = 391.995 Hz --- Duty Cycle = 122
            begin
                ac_counter_G4 <= ac_counter_G4 + 1'b1;
                if (ac_counter_G4 >= 8'd121)
                    ac_counter_G4 <= 8'd0;
                write_audio_out <= 1'b1;
                dac_out = (ac_counter_G4 < 8'd61) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
            end
        else if (SW[5] == 1'b1) // A4 --- f = 440 Hz --- Duty Cycle = 110
            begin
                ac_counter_A4 <= ac_counter_A4 + 1'b1;
                if (ac_counter_A4 >= 8'd109)
                    ac_counter_A4 <= 8'd0;
                write_audio_out <= 1'b1;
                dac_out = (ac_counter_A4 < 8'd55) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
            end
        else if (SW[6] == 1'b1) // B4 --- f = 493.883 Hz --- Duty Cycle = 98
            begin
                ac_counter_B4 <= ac_counter_B4 + 1'b1;
                if (ac_counter_B4 >= 8'd97)
                    ac_counter_B4 <= 8'd0;
                write_audio_out <= 1'b1;
                dac_out = (ac_counter_B4 < 8'd44) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
            end
        else // NO SWITCH ON --- DEFAULT STATE
            begin

                ac_counter_C4 <= 1'd0;
                ac_counter_D4 <= 1'd0;
                ac_counter_E4 <= 1'd0;
                ac_counter_F4 <= 1'd0;
                ac_counter_G4 <= 1'd0;
                ac_counter_A4 <= 1'd0;
                ac_counter_B4 <= 1'd0;

                write_audio_out <= 1'b0;
                clear_audio_out_memory <= 1'b1;
                dac_out <= 1'b0;
            end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your system correctly, shouldn't you be generating sine wave amplitude values of the specified frequency as input for your DAC? . If you feed 2-amplitude signal to the DAC, I am supposing the analog output is also a square wave, which is essentially a combination of your required base frequency, and higher order harmonics(These might be contributing to apparent higher pitches).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I ended up figuring out the problem. Turns out the clock I was using (DAC_XCK) wasn't what I thought it was. Still not sure how exactly it works, but I changed it to CLOCK_50 (50MHz clock), changed all the duty cycles to match this change, and it works perfectly now. I've even got it to change octaves and play multiple notes at the same time! A lot of progress happened last night and I'm pretty excited.